# HTML5 Video API is not showing videos but producing sound

Tags: php, laravel, html5-video

I am building a Web Application with Laravel. I want to add a video to a particular section using HTML5 video API, the video is only playing sound but not showing. This is my code below

```
<video controls width="450" height="300" autoplay="false">   
    <source src="{{ asset('site/videos/iUOL Welcome Video.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{ asset('site/videos/iUOL Welcome Video.flv') }}" type="video/flv">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

I have tested it on Chromium, Firefox and Chrome all the same.

Comment: Probably impossible for us to determine from what you have shown so far, what the actual issue might be. What have you done so far to try and narrow it down?

Comment: @04FS Thanks very much. I think the problem comes from the video. After hours of searching, I just thought of using another video for testing which fortunately works perfectly. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your video is properly encoded, then only it will support HTML5 video tag.

HTML5 video need MP4 videos with H264 video codec and AAC audio codec.

Convert your video mp4 file to H.264 encoding and check.

Comment: Thanks, the problem comes from the video. It was encoded wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the spaces from the video name?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your css? Here issue is in your style sheet.

If the video is sounding then it's working fine in autoplay mode.

```
<div class="video">
// Add your code here.
</div>
```

Css should be:

```
.video{
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100% !important;
 }
```